# How do I export JPEGs from Lightroom without the grey/black box around each picture?

Tags: software, lightroom, jpeg

How do I export JPEGs from Lightroom without the grey/black box around each picture?

This is really frustrating me. I know there has to be a way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the images in the *Library* module and click "Export..." in the lower left.

It sounds as if you might be using the *Print* module to export to files.

Comment: I was in slideshow mode!